# Loop through multiple checkbox in visual c++

Tags: loops, visual-c++, checkbox, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to make a simple form in Visual C++ 2013 Ultimate in Windows 7 for a side-project I'm developing.
I have brand names & Categories. These values are come from database. When an user clicked in a brand he will prompted to choice which categories should enlisted for this brand.

An example an user may clicked "Sony"
Then he will prompted in a form for choosing Categories like:
Laptop, Desktop, Smartphone, Keyboard, Mouse, Monitor, RAM, ....

Actually I want to create checkboxes programmatically.

```
int^ countedvalue;
countedvalue = count_all_categories();
String* checkBox[] = new String* [countedvalue];
while(mysql->Read()){
String^ i = mysql->GetString(0);
String^ cat = mysql->GetString(1);
    this->checkBox[i] = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
    this->checkBox[i]->AutoSize = true;
    this->checkBox[i]->Location = System::Drawing::Point(21, 249);
    this->checkBox[i]->Name = cat;
    this->checkBox[i]->Size = System::Drawing::Size(80, 17);
    this->checkBox[i]->TabIndex = 14;
    this->checkBox[i]->Text = L"chk"+i;
    this->checkBox[i]->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this->Controls->Add(this->checkBox[i]);
delete i;
}
```

I am trying to define checkBox[i] programmatically. And I have no knowledge how to do it out of any method.